# Why parenthesis is needed in this Coffeescript?

Tags: coffeescript

I have this piece of code

```
  @_showSection(
    { redirect: url, token: token },
    FailedView)
```

In Coffeescript, parenthesis is optional, so I tried to remove them

```
  @_showSection
    { redirect: url, token: token },
    FailedView
```

I got a `SyntaxError: unexpected INDENT`

I tried a few other changes e.g.

```
  @_showSection
      redirect: url, token: token
    FailedView
```

They are not accepted by coffeescript compiler either.

Why in this case the removal of parenthesis is not acceptable?

Comment: Works if you leave out the braces and the parentheses too.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks for the comment. I would like to learn what is the syntactical rule behind it

Comment: I have no idea what the rule is or even if there is a rule. I'd guess that this is a side effect of the disambiguation stuff that tries to figure out what you mean when optional things are left out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
@_showsection
  redirect: url, token: token
  FailedView
```

And your indentation is wrong in the second example. You also can put the key/value pairs each on one line.

```
@_showsection
  redirect: url
  token: token
  FailedView
```

What doesn't work, is putting the object argument on its own line with braces.

**Edit**:
If you want a solution with braces, you could go with something like this:

```
@_showsection {
    redirect: url,
    token: token
  },
  FailedView
```

Also, if you want *all* the extras, you can use the shortened syntax for object description (if you use braces):

```
@_showsection {
     redirect: url,
     token},
   FailedView
```

I still couldn't find one where the first argument starts on the second line with a brace.

Comment: While this works of course it is barely readable especially in larger code structures.

Comment: @Exinferis: I added some suggestions with braces. Also, the question even has the argument on one line, so my guess was that it wasn't a that complex data structure.

Comment: @Exinferis It's perfectly readable... How does the presence or absence of surrounding `{}` make any difference to readability in a language where leading indentation denotes blocking?

Comment: @meagar: I think @Exinfernis is reffering to the second code block, It is admittedly a little confusing that the fourth line is on another level than the line above. (they all translate to `this._showsection({redirect: url,token: token}, FailedView);`)

Comment: @PatrickJ.S. Thanks for the great answer! I am still new to CS so this kind of syntax looks a bit arbitrary to me. What are the syntactical rules behind these variations? Any pointer or reference is appreciated.